# Add a status indicator column in an OOTB Project Tasks List?

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, business-intelligence

We have an OOTB Project Tasks List that works great for our needs.

However I was looking to make it a little more quicker and easier to read.

I would like to add a column called "status" and have three main colored circles (Red, Green and Yellow) to indicate the health of each of the project tasks.

I am assuming that the indicators would be driven by the percentage complete field on each task. But ideally would love to drive it with a calculated value based on a Time/Percent complete ratio.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will do what you are asking for SP 2007 and higher. The Status indicator show Green and Red, but you can modify the calculated field to have the Status column show a third color as well.

The output will look like so:
[image]

Steps:

1. Create a **Status** column (Calculated field) and a **Status Text** column (Choice field)

   [image]
2. Configure the Status column like so:

   [image]
3. Configure the Status Text column like so:

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not  available out of the box.

My blog features a technique that I call the **HTML Calculated Column** that can do what you want. You might want to start with the article I published this week (it directly answers your question about percent complete), but there are dozens of others:

[Trick or Treat? Text to html, the wicked no-code way](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2012/10/31/trick-or-treat-text-to-html-the-wicked-no-code-way/)

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in calculated column field to show status indicator based on your column value

```
<div style='font-weight:bold;  line-height:50%; align-center;font-size:36px; color:"&CHOOSE(LEFT([your column value],1),"gray","green","orange","red")&";'>•</div>
```